# How can a simple linear regression be a discriminative model?

Tags: regression, machine-learning

On Wikipedia, I just read that linear regression can be referred to as a discriminative model in the [Discriminative Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminative_model) article.

[image]

The link brings to the "Simple Linear Regression" page.

However, I also read in the same article that a discriminative model

> distinguish decision boundaries through observed data, such as pass/fail, win/lose, alive/dead or healthy/sick.

This definition in my mind sticks better to a classification model (where I separate classes by means of a decision boundary) than a regression model...
How can a simple linear regression, for instance, be consistent with such a definition?

Comment: I cannot find any statement in the referenced article to that effect: it is explicitly about *logistic* regression, not "simple linear regression."

Comment: Hi, if you scroll down the article till you reach the "Types" section, you will see linear regression listed down along with logistic regression (see the screenshot I added to my question)

Comment: If you can make a line, then you can classify (aka mathematically discriminate) one side from the other. Discrimination has the same soul as regression. To fit a model is, fundamentally, the ability to separate types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A discriminative model means that the model discriminates between values of the outcome. Therefore, even though a linear regression is not drawing a decision boundary between two categories, it is discriminating between an outcome of $1$ vs an outcome of $1.1$ vs an outcome of $0.9$.

If your brain has a good handle on categorical discrimination, perhaps start thinking of linear regression as discriminating between high and low predictions. Then think of discriminating between high, medium, and low. Then think of discriminating between high, medium-high, medium-low, and low. Then think of discriminating between high, medium-high, medium, medium-low, and low.

Linear regression then takes the partitioning to the continuum (ditto for any other kind of "regression" model that predicts values on a continuum).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! It makes sense :)